# Ubuntu OpenStack and What Did I Miss Here?

Tags: server, cloud, openstack

I downloaded [Ubuntu OpenStack](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-cloud) (it's the second "entry" on the page). The download link took me to [Ubuntu Server for Cloud](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/thank-you?distro=server&bits=64&release=latest) (where the download began). I downloaded the latest server package, which is 13.10.

The best I can tell, there's no Cloud stuff on that CD. When I installed the server package, I was asked if I wanted to enable the SSH server, the SAMBA server, install a print server, etc. But there was no choice for "Cloud Server".

Additionally, after reboot, there is nothing running that looks like its cloud related, like Keystone (identity management), Glance (image manager), Nova or Nuetron (compute), Ceph or Swift (object storage), etc.

I'm obviously missing something, here, but I don't know what it is. The advertised steps are:

- [Download Ubuntu Server for Cloud](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud)
- Create a startup disk USB Stick
- Insert it in your computer and reboot
- Start using your local private cloud

OpenStack is moving so fast my recipes for installing it and running it on Ubuntu are already ancient. That includes my books like [OpenStack Cloud Computing Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849517320).

What, precisely, does Ubuntu OpenStack provide? Am I supposed to do something else next (apparently, but I don't know what)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are ***three* (3) different Ubuntu OpenStack installation options**, depending on whether you plan to build your own infrastructure, run Ubuntu as a guest on existing infrastructure (be it public or private) or you want to deploy services on a working cloud with Juju Charms.

1. Ubuntu Cloud Guest:

   This can be done using any of the existing services: Amazon EC2, HP Cloud, Windows Azure, Rackspace Cloud. You only need to execute `cloud-init` and follow the instructions.
2. Ubuntu OpenStack:

   This could be archived downloading the server image and following the [OpenStack documentation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure) There's also the [MAAS route.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS)
3. Juju Charms

   This only requires an existing Ubuntu installation, installing Juju and deploy charms. This is the easiest in case you don't want to deploy immediately.

Comment: Thanks Braiam. For option two, the only text I see is "The easiest way to try Ubuntu OpenStack is to create a bootable USB stick that will let you try OpenStack." What page are you on?

Comment: "See the Ubuntu OpenStack documentation for details." at the end.

Comment: @noloader Havana http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/