# Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS - Where is the Openstack?

Tags: openstack

I installed the Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS from this page ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) which informs that in this package includes the IceHouse Openstack.

However, I can't find any reference in the system for Openstack and/or its components (Horizon, Nova etc).

Is there any specific thing that I'm doing wrong?? The system is running fine....but nothing about Openstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Distributions release OpenStack packages as part of the distribution or using other methods because of differing release schedules."

From: http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_basic_environment.html#basics-packages

Answer (score 1):

That means that the default repositories do contain the packages for installing OpenStack, but you have to install and configure all the components yourself (by hand, or using some tool). Alternatively, you can install Ubuntu with MaaS and install the OpenStack with juju.

You can also use the autopilot. I personally didn't manage to get it working on Ubuntu 14.04 due to dependency problems. But it did work well on 15.10.
Check out this link:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot

Update:
Here is another link to a similar question: [Ubuntu OpenStack and What Did I Miss Here?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394926/ubuntu-openstack-and-what-did-i-miss-here?rq=1)